# Error Inserting <Table> into Email

Tags: c#, html-table, smtp, html-email

I am trying to insert a table into an email.  I have the following error on 6 lines of code (Starting with "body" ending onavgErrorOutStDev += "/table").  The error is:

> "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer".

The `<table>` starts is a method performed before the email is created/sent. How do I fix the error?

```
MailMessage errorOutStanDev = new MailMessage();
        errorOutStanDev.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient SmtpServerThree = new SmtpClient("smtp.xxxx.xxx");
        errorOutStanDev.From = new 
System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("PerformanceUpdate@xxx.xxx");
        errorOutStanDev.To.Add(new 
System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx"));
        string htmlBody = "<body>" +
                          "<p><b> The following errors have occurred more 
 often than others</b></p>" +
                          avgErrorOutStDev += "<tr>" +
                          avgErrorOutStDev += "<td>" + sitename + "</td>"+ 
                          avgErrorOutStDev += "<td>" + avg + "</td>" +
                          avgErrorOutStDev += "</tr>" +
                          avgErrorOutStDev += "</table>" +
                          "</body>";
```

Comment: `"" + x += ""` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SLaks Just edited

Comment: The error is trying to tell you that your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SLaks How do I get the code to work?  I have tried populating the table in the previous method, but then I get 10 duplicate entries.

Comment: Either use `+` in one statement or `+=` in multiple statements.  You need to learn the basics of C# syntax & string concatenation.

Comment: @Aniket Betkikar I will give that a shot...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StringBuilder when building the body. The code looks much cleaner. This should work.

```
    string avgErrorOutStDev = string.Empty;
                avgErrorOutStDev += "<tr>";
                avgErrorOutStDev += "<td>" + sitename + "</td>";
                avgErrorOutStDev += "<td>" + avg + "</td>";
                avgErrorOutStDev += "</tr>";
                avgErrorOutStDev += "</table>";

                StringBuilder htmlBody = new StringBuilder();
                htmlBody.AppendLine("<body>");
                htmlBody.AppendLine("<p><b> The following errors have occurred more often than others </ b ></ p >");
                htmlBody.AppendLine(avgErrorOutStDev);
                htmlBody.AppendLine("</ body >");

                htmlBody.ToString();
```